# Can I create a c++ library that links another library but doesnt depend on its includes?

Tags: c++, header, include, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I want to create a dynamic/static library that links the `SFML` library and others. My problem right now is that when unsing my library in a project I have to make sure the `SFML includes` are available to that project.
*Can I somehow remove this dependency on third party headers?*
*How about `header-only` libraries?*

How do other libraries handle this (when using `SFML`, I only need their headers even though `SFML` depends on other libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to reorganize your header files and restructure your code. You will need to have two sets of header files:

- The internal header files that are used to build your library, and these header files include and reference `SFML`'s header files, classes, and resources.
- The public header files that comprise the interface to your library.

Your library installs only the public set. The public header files do not include `SFML` header files, and they don't reference any `SFML` classes.

Your public header files and classes will typically declare, but not define, internal classes, and pointers to them. The internal classes are defined only in your own internal header files.

You should spend some time looking at header files from some large, popular C++ library. You will often find pointers and other references to internal classes that are not defined in the public header files. They are internal classes used by the library, which are not publicly exposed.

Even many C libraries are structured this way, too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :), so would this come up with the same problem?    
I have a class A(`A.h`/`A.cpp`) that includes a SFML header. I now have `B.h` that includes `A.h`. When using the library and including its `B.h`, do I still need the headers?

Comment: Yes. If A.h includes an SFML header, it will be required. Rewrite B.h so that it doesn't include A.h. As I told: go look at how other libraries do this.

Comment: If this doesnt work, the only way to remove the depency on the `SFML` includes is via `Forward-Declaration` right? But what if I need a normal `SFML-type` member?

Comment: As I explained: put these objects in an internal class, with a pointer from the public class, defined in a public header file, to a forwardly-declared internal class. You're hiding everything `SFML`-related in internal classes, that are forwardly declared only, in the public headers. ... you don't even need a pointer. You can declare containers of forwardly-declared classes, i.e. std::vector<internal_class>. Only when its constructed, or referenced, does the internal_class's definition need to be available.

Comment: Ok, can you suggest me a library where I can easily see how they have done it? Ill look into the SFML source too, maybe I can find sth there

Comment: Im sorry, but I think I dont understand it fully(I think an Example would help me :) ) : Lets say I have an `Object`(Object.h/Object.cpp) that needs to have a texture. I would like to use `sf::Texture` for that, but I dont want to use a pointer to a `sf::Texture` in `Object`, nor a reference. How would I go about it now?

Comment: What part of "a pointer from the public class" you did not understand? You have a pointer to an internal class in your public class, and you have that sf::Texture in the internal class. Your internal class is forwardly-declared, and defined and used only in your library's private headers. Or, perhaps, as I explained, you could use a container instead of a pointer. This is called "information hiding". That's how C and C++ work. If you don't want use pointers or containers, you'll have to find some other language to write code in, instead of C or C++. Because that's how C & C++ work.

Comment: I wanted to clarify it, and no I dont have a problem with pointers. It was just a hypothetical question about how to handle such a case. Anyways thank you for your answer